# Everytime I go to render preview with cycles this is the result I get? I don't know if it is something to do with local view maybe?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

[image]

I have checked my camera and enable d surfaces

Comment: I am a beginner and help is needed !

Comment: Hello maybe share your file?

Comment: @moonboots is there a direct way to share on this platform

Comment: You can use https://blend-exchange.com/ read the instructions, or use another platform like workupload, in both case share the link here

Comment: @moonboots I've shared on wetransfer https://we.tl/t-zj3zORvQnA

Comment: It's too heavy, it makes my computer crash, but if I keep only the mountain it works fine, maybe share a siplified version that still has the problem?